# Running a .ps1 file from another

Tags: powershell

I created a file `config.ps1` which includes the variables [details of servers]:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010

#VMware Variables
$vcenterserver = "xyz@vsphere.local"

#Netview Variables
$netviewservers = "Sinpe.insta.org"

#Ping Servers
$pingservers = @("www.google.com","www.facebook.com","www.cricinfo.com")

#Xen Desktop Variables
$ddcserverconnection = "ddc.spawn.local"

#PVS Variables
$pvsservers = "ASPPVS02"
```

I have written some .ps1 scripts for VMWare, SQL, Xen Desktop etc.

Ex: I have written the following for PING:

```
. .\config.ps1
$body += echo "-----------------------------Ping results for servers-------------------------------"`r`n""`r`n""
$body += foreach ($server in $pingservers) {
    echo "$server"`r`n""
    Test-Connection $server |
        ft @{expression={$_.__server};label="Source Server"},
           @{expression={$_.ipv4address};label="IP address"},
           @{expression={$_.responsetime};label="Response time"} |
        Out-String
}
Write-Output $body
```

I got the following response:

```
Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010'
is not installed on this computer.
At C:\Users\admin\Desktop\config.ps1:1 char:1
+ Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Excha...owerShell.E2010:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand

-----------------------------Ping results for servers-------------------------------

www.google.com

Source Server IP address     Response time
------------- ----------     -------------
DEV01 74.195.130.104            93
DEV01 74.195.130.104            93
DEV01 74.195.130.104            93
DEV01 74.195.130.104            96

facebook.com

Source Server IP address    Response time
------------- ----------    -------------
DEV01 74.163.87.234           348
DEV01 74.163.87.234           381
DEV01 74.163.87.234           294
DEV01 74.163.87.234           272

www.cricinfo.com

Source Server IP address   Response time
------------- ----------   -------------
DEV01 184.25.57.18            27
DEV01 184.25.57.18           157
DEV01 184.25.57.18           207
DEV01 184.25.57.18            73
```

How could I eliminate that error? I want the script to only take `$pingservers` variable from it instead of running everything.

Comment: Dot-source the `config.ps1` script from the others, ie. `. .\config.ps1` or `. $PSScriptRoot\config.ps1` on the first line

Comment: Should I include .\config.ps1 in my other scripts? Is that what u said?

Comment: Dot sourcing will set the variables from the called script in the scope of the scripting that is calling it. If you want variables defined from `config.ps1` then add a line in the script dot sourcing config.ps1 like Mathias showed.

Comment: I have done what u said and I changed my question above. Please look into it.

Comment: You have `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010` in the config.ps1. If you don't want this to run then you would need to remove that line.

Comment: I have done that. Now, I don't have that line in my config.ps1. But still, it shows the same error. I restarted my system too. Same error is being shown up

Comment: Yaa...finally, it disappeared.